Debian - help with debugging / unstability issue
i am running debian on google vmare
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

and i'm facing some instability debian freezing without a reason. Not able to ssh to the machine or use www, but network is up. I need to stop and resume the vmare in google cloud to start it.
on the machine:
openvpn server - running without issues
MariaDB Started MariaDB 10.5.26 database server.
apache2 2.4
what i notice is runnig apache2 and mariaDB togethet is causing the freez, when i turn them down system is stable for a long time. Running the apache2 + MariaDB to host wordpress site is killing the machine in 2-3 days.
I notice strange /var/log behaviour casued by improper logging configuration - but i am not sure how to solve it.
    ls -la
total 72392
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug  9 13:10 --MSMQ
drwxr-xr-x  270 root        root               20480 Oct  6 00:00 .
drwxr-xr-x   13 root        root                4096 Apr 24  2022 ..
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep 11 16:17 103.56.61.130
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 20 19:59 159.89.27.186
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 16 16:47 159.89.99.95
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 14 10:24 161.35.65.47
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug  4 00:04 164.92.129.90
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun  2 23:35 165.22.95.16
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep 18 10:45 165.232.77.115
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 16 15:12 167.99.242.227
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 May 30 20:42 172-104-210-105.ip.linodeusercontent.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug  2 21:07 173-255-221-189.ip.linodeusercontent.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 19 20:59 179.60.147.131
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  9 16:28 179.60.149.54
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  6 01:31 179.60.149.8
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun  3 22:07 185.11.61.106
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  2 23:50 185.232.67.46
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 19 21:24 193.29.13.21
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 11 20:22 194.169.175.57
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 22 15:00 194.180.48.25
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 30 22:18 206.81.18.156
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 23 04:28 206.81.29.55
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug  9 21:53 207.154.196.207
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug  9 21:31 207.154.207.218
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  6 01:02 209.38.194.71
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 14 13:33 209.38.196.175
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 25 12:25 209.38.241.178
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 30 18:48 209.38.241.214
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 20 23:06 209.38.244.65
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 28 04:03 213.109.202.5
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 19 07:32 222.186.13.132
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  5 07:28 36.156.22.4
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep 14 20:36 45-79-115-117.ip.linodeusercontent.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 18 20:40 45-79-115-134.ip.linodeusercontent.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 24 20:35 45-79-163-53.ip.linodeusercontent.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 27 08:23 45.129.14.224
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun  4 00:51 45.227.254.8
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep 12 07:12 46.101.122.84
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 28 13:09 46.101.164.191
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 23 11:07 46.101.219.165
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 13 17:03 64.225.100.148
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 13 01:29 64.225.105.114
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 25 09:07 64.226.64.152
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep  3 05:07 64.226.81.60
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 16 19:23 68.183.216.86
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun  5 23:03 80.66.76.121
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  2 04:29 80.66.76.130
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 16 19:40 80.66.76.134
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  7 21:38 88.214.25.65
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 30 22:34 91.217.249.188
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  1 13:12 91.238.181.21
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  4 02:37 91.238.181.22
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul  7 09:45 91.238.181.24
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 21 03:35 91.238.181.71
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 14 20:14 92.255.85.100
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 30 08:18 92.255.85.102
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep  3 10:26 94.156.66.15
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep  7 22:08 94.156.69.95
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 May 30 20:36 GET
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 May 29 21:18 MGLNDD_34.130.102.20_514
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun  1 04:12 OPTIONS
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 26 19:18 POST
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 27 08:47 User
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 25 23:31 adorable.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 26 07:13 adored.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jul 22 07:47 adventuresome.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 22 22:33 affectionate.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 25 14:43 alluring.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
-rw-r--r--    1 root        root                   0 Sep 20 00:00 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r--    1 root        root                 112 Sep 19 06:32 alternatives.log.1
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep 21 02:12 angelic.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwxr-x---    3 root        adm                 4096 Oct  6 12:36 apache2
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 25 23:29 appealing.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwxr-xr-x    2 root        root                4096 Oct  5 06:25 apt
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 22 22:33 astounding.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Sep 25 00:49 attentive.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwxr-x---    2 root        adm                 4096 Oct  5 23:51 audit
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 22 05:51 auspicious.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
-rw-r-----    1 root        adm                86539 Oct  6 12:53 auth.log
-rw-r-----    1 root        adm              3313735 Oct  5 23:39 auth.log.1
-rw-r-----    1 root        adm                18883 Oct  3 00:00 auth.log.2.gz
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 22 00:16 awesome.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 23 08:09 beautiful.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 25 14:40 breezy.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
-rw-rw----    1 root        utmp             2793216 Oct  6 12:53 btmp
-rw-rw----    1 root        utmp            20868480 Oct  1 00:00 btmp.1
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 25 23:28 bubbly.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Aug 22 22:33 buoyant.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 25 23:29 calm.monitoring.internet-measurement.com
drwx------    2 root        root                4096 Jun 23 08:09 celebrated.monitoring.inte

I can't see any error in the daemon.log, dmesg etc. The instance is not overloaded cpu/mem/disk not sure what to do more
